# How to add android tools dir to windows 7 path?

Tags: android, hierarchyviewer

I like to quickly start hierarchyviewer. At the moment i use the prompt to go navigate to .... \AppData\local\android\android-sdk\tools\ and then hierarchyviewer

I think i need to add something to windows 7 path, but i don't know what to do exactly.

Any suggestions?

regards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Suppose you have download and install Android SDK, and extract it in some drive. There are two methods to set PATH:

Use command prompt :

```
set path=%path%;D:\android-sdk-windows\tools;
```

Another is follow these steps :

```
My Computer->Property->Advanced->Environment Variables->Edit Path Variable and add “D:\ android-sdk-windows\tools” into the Path Variables.
```

Comment: It is a good idea to also add the `platform-tools` folder to your path.

Comment: If you already have Android Studio installed and just looking where did it install the SDK for you, here's where it was on my machine: `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`. So the command above would look like `set path=%path%;%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;`

Comment: Do not forget about the ";" when doing the "Another is..." section.

Answer (score 2):

In your computer properties-advance-environment variables-system variable ,and you find variable "path", add your android/tools path in it.

The operate like add java.exe in you computer path

Comment: If the SDK lies at your personal `AppData`, it might be a better idea to add the path to the _User_ Environment Variable instead of the _System_ Environment Variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

and add it you your Path User variable