# How to install an apk file in emulator using command prompt?

Tags: android

I am installing apk file in emulator using command prompt but it is giving message on cmd prompt

```
adb is not recognized as an external and internal command
```

Even I'm giving correct path and trying again and again but i am unable to install. please give some idea, is there any another way?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your computer can't find adb. Try adding the android tools to your path.

If you are using windows:
[How to add android tools dir to windows 7 path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285670/how-to-add-android-tools-dir-to-windows-7-path)