# Phonegap build error

Tags: cordova

I'm very new to phonegap and tried to create a simple test app by entering the commands like described on the phonegap install webpage.

I use Windows 7 64-bit.

Unfortunately, I get the following error in the command-line:

```
  -pre-compile:   

   -compile:    
   [javac] Compiling 93 source files to D:\phonegap_project\test5\platforms\and
roid\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes

[javac] D:\phonegap_project\test5\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apach

e\cordova\CordovaWebView.java:266: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable KITKAT
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES

    [javac] D:\phonegap_project\test5\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\com\squar
eup\okhttp\internal\http\HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347: error: method does not
 override or implement a method from a supertype

    [javac]   @Override public void setFixedLengthStreamingMode(long contentLeng
th) {
    [javac]   ^


    [javac] D:\phonegap_project\test5\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apach
e\cordova\CordovaWebView.java:230: error: cannot find symbol


    [javac]             android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VER
SION_CODES.KITKAT) {


    [javac]       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable KITKAT
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] D:\phonegap_project\test5\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apach
e\cordova\CordovaWebView.java:269: error: cannot find symbol

    [javac]             WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

    [javac]                    ^


    [javac]   symbol:   method setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)
    [javac]   location: class WebView

    [javac] D:\phonegap_project\test5\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apach
e\cordova\IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.
VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && "content".equals(uri.getScheme());
    [javac]
             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable KITKAT
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES

    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 5 errors


BUILD FAILED
D:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The foll
owing error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The foll
owing error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile
failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds


D:\phonegap_project\test5\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\phonegap_project\
test5\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen


Error: D:\phonegap_project\test5\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command fa
iled with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pho
negap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:13
5:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: Do you have the `android sdk` installed on your machine and added to your `path`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My quick guess is that you installed a version of Android SDK tools that is too old for the version of cordova you're using.

The message says Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT is not found and indicates that it's just the KITKAT part that is unknown not Build.VERSION_CODES, so I deduct that

- you correctly insalled android sdk and added to the path
- you installed a version of Cordova that requires minimum Android SDK 19
- but you have an older version of the sdk platform insalled.

To correct your problem, run the `android` command in a terminal and then upgrade **Android sdk tools** and **Android SDK Platform** to version 19 (KitKat) or greater.

Comment: I updated to latest version of cordova and now it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are three parts needed to be able to build Android in Cordova:

1. Android SDK must be installed (at the very least the stand alone SDK tools).
2. Android.exe / SDK must be added to your PATH.
3. Update the Android SDK after installation to be sure you have the latest.

#### Installing Android SDK

For this to work, you need the ANDROID SDK installed. The [download page is here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other).

#### Add Android SDK directory to PATH

Once you've installed the SDK, [you need to add it to your PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285670/how-to-add-android-tools-dir-to-windows-7-path).

The PATH value you give will be wherever you installed it.

#### Updating Android SDK via Command Line

Once you do that, run:

```
android update sdk --no-ui
```

from the command line to ensure you have the latest SDK.  And then try your build again.